# Не могу обратиться к свойству кнопки из кода

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Наткнулся на непонятную проблему при написании приложения на *Xamarin Forms*.

У меня есть следующий код `.xaml`:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SalaryCalculator.View.PageAlisaMenu">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
      <Button x:Name="abc"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Когда я пытаюсь обратиться к `abc.Text` из `.xaml.cs`, *VS* пишет, что `abc` нет. При этом в `MainPage` такое работает, а вот в остальных добавленных страницах нет.

Comment: Название вашего xaml файла соответствует классу, что вы в нем указали? `Class="SalaryCalculator.View.PageAlisaMenu`

Comment: MVVM и Binding вас точно спасёт

Comment: @tym32167, да, оба файла создавались одной кнопкой

Comment: @aepot, да, я понимаю, но хотелось разобраться почему у возникла такая проблема

Answer (score 0):

Автоматически не было сгенерирован код кнопки в файле `.xaml.g.cs`.

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
        private global::Xamarin.Forms.Button abc;
```